# Как с нуля развернуть существующий проект на React имея готовый билд?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, react-native

Есть часть исходников проекта написанного на react.

Вопрос: возможно ли из исходников с нуля развернуть этот проект для редактирования?

Если да, то каким образом?

Из файлов в наличии:
несколько билд файлов js и css с названиями по типу

- runtime-main.3e0d1a11.js
- main.44f0ade4.chunk.js. map
- 2.d96c7068.chunk.js.map

из json, txt и html файлов есть только

- asset-manifest
- manifest.json
- LICENSE.txt
- index.html

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Так если у Вас только билд, а не сами исходники, как и что Вы собираетесь редактировать? Билд перекомпилирован вебпаком в слюни.